# channel from process output in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

Can I generate a channel from a process output in Nextflow?

E.g.

```
process bam2fastq {
    conda 'samtools'

    input:
        path bam_file

    output:
        path 'fq1', emit: fastq1
        path 'fq2', emit: fastq2
        stdout // out[2]

    shell:
    '''
    samtools fastq !{bam_file} -1 fq1 -2 fq2
    echo !{bam_file} | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}' | sed 's/.bam//'
    '''    
}
```

Then, in the workflow (dsl2)

```
files = Channel.fromPath( params.input_files )

reads = bam2fastq(files)
library = bam2fastq.out[2]


a = Channel.of(reads.fastq1, reads.fastq2, library)
```

Or ideally:

```
Channel.of(bam2fastq)
```

When I print the output variables from the process bam2fastq I get:
`DataflowBroadcast around DataflowStream[?]`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [output](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#outputs) block already lets you to define the output channels of a process. I think a better approach here would be to pass in the library name using a [tuple](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-type-tuple). You could also output a tuple so that you have a 'key' to more easily handle the outputs downstream. If the library name is just the basename of the BAM, you could use the [`fromFilePairs`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs) factory method to extract it for you. For example:

```
params.input_files = './path/to/bams/*.bam'


process bam2fastq {

    tag { library }

    input:
    tuple val(library), path(bam_file)

    output:
    tuple val(library), path("${library}.{1,2}.fastq.gz")

    """
    samtools fastq \\
        -1 "${library}.1.fastq.gz" \\
        -2 "${library}.2.fastq.gz" \\
        -0 /dev/null \\
        -s /dev/null \\
        -n \\
        "${bam_file}"
    """
}

workflow {

    input_ch = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.input_files, size: 1 )

    bam2fastq( input_ch )

    bam2fastq.out.view()
}
```

With:

```
$ find ./path/to/bams/
./path/to/bams/
./path/to/bams/C.markdup.sorted.bam
./path/to/bams/A.markdup.sorted.bam
./path/to/bams/B.markdup.sorted.bam
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run -ansi-log false main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [mad_torvalds] DSL2 - revision: d6f550efc0
[be/7e76ac] Submitted process > bam2fastq (B.markdup.sorted)
[24/54381e] Submitted process > bam2fastq (C.markdup.sorted)
[8d/ddddeb] Submitted process > bam2fastq (A.markdup.sorted)
[C.markdup.sorted, [/path/to/work/24/54381e1d52ab8066150bdb1d6fe734/C.markdup.sorted.1.fastq.gz, /path/to/work/24/54381e1d52ab8066150bdb1d6fe734/C.markdup.sorted.2.fastq.gz]]
[B.markdup.sorted, [/path/to/work/be/7e76ac22e05a6caa2410299918e7e6/B.markdup.sorted.1.fastq.gz, /path/to/work/be/7e76ac22e05a6caa2410299918e7e6/B.markdup.sorted.2.fastq.gz]]
[A.markdup.sorted, [/path/to/work/8d/ddddeb7c3a1501191c99e8fafd7232/A.markdup.sorted.1.fastq.gz, /path/to/work/8d/ddddeb7c3a1501191c99e8fafd7232/A.markdup.sorted.2.fastq.gz]]
```